# Creating custom jframe dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm doing simple ATM transaction application using java swing. I'm using Jframe form as the front end design. All i need is to create a custom jframe window like  avast antivirus window having different close, maximize and minimize buttons on the top.
Thats all thank you.

Comment: Good, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

- create undecorated `JFrame`, put there `JPanel` with `Border`s, change the `LayoutManager` to `BorderLayout`
- put another `JPanel` to `NORTH area`, with three undecorated `JButton`s and to set `setIcons`, `setRolloverIcon`, `setPressedIcon` with desired `Icon`s
- have to use proper `LayoutManager` for `JPanel` with three `JButton`s, but, probably, maybe `FlowLayout` (default `LayoutManager` for `JPanel`) is proper for this job, and/or you would need to set `alignment` for `FlowLayout`
- for every those `JButtons` is required to override proper event from `WindowListener`, the same event as for `standard decorated JFrame`
- every of my steps (that I'm talking about) are described in [Oracles tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)